# Testing a Rust crate outside of the source package

Tags: rust

I have created my Rust crate. It's a very trivial affair. It built fine and when tested within it's own source directory works just fine (I just included `extern crate my_first_crate;` in my test file).

I want to now test the crate in a totally different application.

If I add the same `extern crate` line to my new application, the compiler tells me that it can't find the crate. I expected this (I'd get the same in C if I told the compiler to link to a library it has no clue about!)

Do I need to copy the my_first_crate.rlib file from the source to the application target/debug folder or is there a way to tell cargo that it needs to link to the rlib file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your crate as a dependency for your application. Add this to your application's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
my_first_crate = { path = "/path/to/crate" }
```

`"/path/to/crate"` is the path to the root of the crate's source (i.e. the directory that contains its `Cargo.toml`). You can use either a relative or an absolute path (but avoid absolute paths if you intend on publishing your code!).

Comment: Thanks. I've added my_first_crate = {path = "."} and put libmy_first_crate.rlib in the root of the project (where the Cargo.toml resides). When I run cargo, I'm getting told that "no matching package named my_first_crate found". Any ideas?

Comment: If I use rustc -L . src/main.rs, the binary is created and can be executed. Partial success, just can't figure out why cargo isn't taking the library

Comment: Cargo works by recompiling the dependencies separately for each project (because each project may use a different set of features for the same crate). It wasn't designed for reusing precompiled crates.